# How to create an array of objects with php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My code currently works how it should with AJAX however if you type something in to be submitted and add then click on another item you want it destroys the table creates a new one without refreshing. I am needing to make this so that it will keep the data in the text field with every selection.

I have tried figuring out how to make it an array of objects but cannot seem to make it work.

Here is my ajax call for the information to gather and to get the div i am writing it to

```
function orderShow(str) {
   if (str == "") {
       document.getElementById("orderText").innerHTML = "";
       return;
   } else {
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
           // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       } else {
           // code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               document.getElementById("orderText").innerHTML+= this.responseText;
           }
       };
       xmlhttp.open("GET","getOrder.php?q="+str,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
   }
}
```

here is my php that formats it and prints it to the table for ajax to place in the table

```
<?php require('includes/procs.php'); ?>

<?php
$PageName="";
$q = intval($_GET['q']);


$sql="SELECT * FROM parts WHERE PartID = '".$q."'";
$result =  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);?>

<?php
while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      echo "<tr class="."orderList"." >";
      echo "<td class="."vendorDetails"." >" . $rs['PartID'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td class="."vendorDetails".">" . $rs['Description'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td class="."vendorDetails"."><input type="."text"." name=".$rs['PartID']." id="."part".$rs['PartID']." onchange='calculatePrice('document.getElementById'('part".$rs['PartID']."').innerHTML;');' value=".""." >
      <input type="."hidden"."  value=".$rs['Price']."></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
  }

echo "
";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I want it to keep the data that has already been typed. However It destroys it. see pictures below
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not good at php : just build a json array of object in a string or make an object and find the right php function to serialize it in json. Then in js just do a JSON.parse(myjsonFromPhp)

Comment: To get the whole picture : do you build a table on the right corresponding to the orders that the customer make by choosing items on the left table ?

Comment: Separe this job in several tasks : maybe you could provide a working example using js arrays of object and when everything is fixed, think about the php side ?

Comment: Yes I build the table on the right by grabbing whatever the user clicks on in the left table right now it works to just put it in the right table. I am not that good with javascript so I have no idea how to make it work with an array of objects I kind of figured that is how I need to do it however no idea how to get there

Comment: instead of building the table with php, you have the option of collecting all of the rows from your database, json_encoding them, pass that data to the browser in a script tag, then use js to build the frontend. I think what you're really after either way is php.net/json_encode

Comment: Look you got the right function from Dale ! You should learn how to uses javascript and json it's great stuff. Maybe if your are stranded, you can do it your way and avoid destroying your table : which pill do you choose ? ;-)

Comment: Dale- It can do whatever it needs to i just need to be able to build the table and have inputs be received calculated and output to the screen

Comment: when you say it destroys the data... do you mean between reloads? I assume you'll have to post the changes back to the server and handle that appropriately

Comment: yeah it just reloads the data and i mean i will have to send it back to the server and I already have that covered. its literally just that my boss does not want it to reload whatever has been typed

Comment: I assume you wanted to add rows but redrew the whole table instead. Do you send all the order with php and try to rebuild the table or do you send only the new order and want to add it to the existing table ?

Comment: He wants you to add the new order to the table. it would be better to retrieve the whole data an redraw the table (it's just a few lines) on the other hand you can send the individual order to the back and return just 'OK 'or 'KO' and add a row to the table with javascript using insertRow function for instance https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Comment: You will need to ajax a request to the server with the newly updated thing to be saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not at ease with js so ad minima you will have to keep an array of objects on the front-end containing your client basket

```
var basket = [];
```

and send new items one at a time to php, 
then php send back to the front the newly stored item in json

```
'{id:852,label:"atomic rocket",price:14544548785}'
```

then you transform this json string into a js object

```
var itemToAdd = JSON.Parse(this.responseText);
```

then you add it to the table :

```
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = itemToAdd.id;
  cell2.innerHTML = itemToAdd.label;
  cell3.innerHTML = itemToAdd.price;
```

That's a start

alternatively you can add the item to your basket

```
basket.push(itemToAdd)
```

and redraw the entire table body

```
var tableBody = document.querySelector("#myTable body");
tableBody.innerhtml = "";
let html="";
basket.forEach(function(x){
   html+= "<tr>";
   html+= "<td>" + x.id + "</td>";
// ... idem with label and price
   html+= "</tr>";
});
tableBody.innerhtml =html;
```

So first : try to send back a string like this one from php

'{id:852,label:"atomic rocket",price:14544548785}'

and add it to the basket

Let's keep in touch and tell us about your progress

Don't look for a recipe, search, understand and apply

See you soon

Answer (score 0):

Soo all I actually had to do to get it to work correctly is change the line

document.getElementById("orderText").innerHTML+= this.responseText;

to

```
$("#orderText").append(this.responseText);
```